# Height of the collection view is getting calculated wrongly while using tabbar controller in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uitabbarcontroller

I have created a tab-bar controller in which a sample view controller is present with a container view. The container is embedded with referencedStoryBoard.
[image]

The reference storyboard contains a view controller within which collectionView controller is embedded. 
[image]

When my app runs the collectionView cell height is calculated wrongly. The collection view cell is getting hidden on the top.

Note: 
1)Collection view scroll direction is horizontal. On vertical side its working good

2) When I am not using the tabBar the collectionView cell height is getting calculated correctly.

You can find the sample project in this link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GbKC_ZhqQAlcLnD24YgxQTZt2toVprwF

The issue is working good in iOS11.

Comment: I made a temporary fix by reloading the collection view in viewDidAppear but that's just a hack

Comment: As I checked, the problem happens after device is rotated. Is it right?

Comment: @trungduc , Nope. rotation is locked in my device

Comment: How about my answer?

Comment: Did you try Auto Layout to constrain the childView to its parent?

Comment: @Koen could your ellaborate your suggestion

Comment: Read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

Answer (score 1):

*Problem* (In my opinion):

- At start-up `SampleCollectionViewController` is created with a normal size (maybe fullscreen size). At this time, `collectionView` is created and reload. Size of `collectionViewCell` is calculated base on size of `SampleCollectionViewController`.
- But after that, `SampleCollectionViewController` is embedded in another controller with a smaller size. Size of `SampleCollectionViewController` change but `collectionView` isn't reloaded and `collectionViewCell` keep start-up size.
- Now height of `collectionViewCell` is bigger than size of `SampleCollectionViewController` on screen. That's why top of the cell is hidden.

*Solution*: Call [invalidateLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617728-invalidatelayout?language=objc) in [traitCollectionDidChange:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitenvironment/1623516-traitcollectiondidchange?language=objc) method. It means that when size of `SampleCollectionViewController` is changed, calculate cell size and update cells with right size.

*SampleCollectionViewController.m*

```
- (void)traitCollectionDidChange:(UITraitCollection *)previousTraitCollection {
  [super traitCollectionDidChange:previousTraitCollection];

  [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}
```

[Project works normally on my side.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10GCUZ87VpPw8owJ6UT_MgvE9d0lpb6Sr/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi trungduc, I tried this code but still the issue occurs. I thought issue is with container view  + tab bar controller. Could you please explain why we need invalidate layout in traitCollectionDidChange. Wont it create issue when it needs to be adjusted

Comment: In SampleCollectionViewController add  [self.collectionView reloadData]; This will show you the difference in output and thanks for briefing your suggestion

Comment: Sorry but can you show your output? I don't see any difference if I uncomment `[self.collectionView reloadData];`

Comment: you can find the expected and actual output from the following link, https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pi7Q-hKiCUQd5E8ibHTyHH4irnnFvyGj

Comment: Did you try project in my answer? Run this project and you will see expected output https://drive.google.com/file/d/10GCUZ87VpPw8owJ6UT_MgvE9d0lpb6Sr/view

Comment: I tried your project and i am seeing the issue. I am running the project in iOS 10, device iPhone 6 could you please inform me your ios version and device type

Comment: I tried on iOS 9.2, 10.3.1 and 11.2 for iPhone 8Plus, iPhone 6, iPhone 5 and none of them got problem

Comment: Thank you, working good in simulator. In iPhone 8 plus and 8 ios 11.3 simulator, works good with and without adding traitCollectionDidChange. Let me try it in the devices by tomorrow but i am able to reproduce the issue in my device ios 10.3.1.

Comment: you should add traitCollectionDidChange, it will help you in iPad split mode. If problem still happens on your device and you don’t want to call reloadData in viewDidAppear, try to use invalidateLayout instead of reloadData

Comment: Wow, that's a great advice for me, I will definitely follow that.

Answer (score 0):

Select your view controller in storyboard. Check if adjust scroll view insets is selected, then unselect it. Thats how i fixed my problem.

Comment: Hi @Jagjot Singh  in my case, its not working. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

When I change the design, I am able to fix that issue for iOS 10. Also working good on iOS 11.

[image]

Instead of container view for storyboard reference, I created a segue to call the storyboard reference. As issue is specific to iOS 10 and horizontal collection view, I am gonna continue with earlier design as mentioned in the question.